# How do I get aggregate results with join in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregate-functions

I have two tables named Purchase and PurchaseOrder and each of the tables have the following fields:

```
Purchase
---------
id
date_shipped
id_po          -> FK of Purchase Order

PurchaseOrder
---------
id
date_po
```

I need to group them based on `PurchaseOrder`'s `date_po` year. So far, I've been using the `date_shipped` field of the `Purchase` table with the following query:

```
select extract(year from date_shipped), count(*) from purchase
    group by(extract(year from date_shipped));
```

Now, I need to join the two tables and group them by the year of `PurchaseOrder`'s `date_po` instead of `Purchase`'s `date_shipped` field. I've tried various queries but can't quite achieve the results. One of the queries I tried is:

```
select extract(year from po.date_shipped), count(*) from purchase p 
    inner join purchase_order po on p.id_po = po.id
    group by(extract(year from po.date_po));
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please be more specific how it doesn't work, because the query as shown will result in an error because your `purchase_order` table has no column `date_shipped`. And the resulting obvious error message should be included in the question, and if that isn't the actual problem, then you need to revise your question to include the actual query and explain why it doesn't work (include sample data, expected result and actual result and why you think that is wrong).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yep, that was supposed to be `date_po` and not `date_shipped`. Updated the question.

Comment: Try ( select Year(po.date_po), count(*) from purchase p 
    inner join purchase_order po on p.id_po = po.id
    group by Year(po.date_po); )

Comment: See the second part of my comment, you need to explain how the query doesn't work.

Comment: @RajneeshVaishwar PostgreSQL has no function `YEAR`, `extract(year from <timestamp/date>)` is the correct function (which is defined in the SQL standard)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Looks like I've been using the wrong column name all this time and failed to notice it. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: As that is the case, I have rolled back your last edit, otherwise the accepted answer makes no sense at all.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Sure thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `group by` clause you can only use terms from there (or row-function applied to them) and aggregate terms in the select list:

```
SELECT     EXTRACT(YEAR FROM po.date_po), COUNT(*)
FROM       purchase p 
INNER JOIN purchase_order po ON p.id_po = po.id
GROUP BY   EXTRACT(YEAR FROM po.date_po)
```

Comment: I had been using the wrong column, it was supposed to be `id_purchase_order` and not `id_po`. Thank's a lot for your time. Accepting answer to stop wasting anyone else's time.